# PHP foreach outputs everything four times (mysql, sql, database administration)

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach

I have some code here which I have a feeling can be made much more efficient. I have been building a library catalogue database, and I am looking for a way to store multiple columns (with multiple entries) extracted from an SQL database into one PHP array. This would mean only one foreach loop would then be required in the 'view' code to print the results out and store them in a table. Any of you guys have useful ideas? :)

My code in its current state is below:

```
MODEL CODE:

$matches["loandates"] = array();
        $matches["loanduedates"] = array();
        $matches["itemnames"] = array();
        $matches["itemauthors"] = array();

        try { // if we do find an item, then we run this query against the database to get a list of all the current loans.
            $results = $db->prepare("
                SELECT il.loan_date, il.loan_duedate, i.item_name, i.item_author 
                FROM itemloan il 
                INNER JOIN libraryitem li
                ON il.libraryItem_id = li.libraryItem_id
                INNER JOIN item i
                ON li.item_id = i.item_id
                WHERE il.user_id = ?
                ORDER BY il.loan_date asc
                    ");
            $results->bindParam(1,$userid); // puts user id value where the placeholder is. First value is character of placeholder, second value is variable we want to bind to placeholder).
            $results->execute();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
                exit;
            }

             while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // we loop through the loans one at a time, and add them to our matches variable
                $matches["loandates"][] = $row["loan_date"];

                $matches["loanduedates"][] = $row["loan_duedate"];

                $matches["itemnames"][] = $row["item_name"];

                $matches["itemauthors"][] = $row["item_author"];

            }

          return $matches;                  
    }
```

VIEW CODE:

```
<table id="name">

                    <?php 
                                    foreach($user["itemnames"] as $itemname) { 

                                            echo "<tr><td id='radiocell'><input type='radio' name='libraryitemid' id='radio'></td><td class='user'>" . $itemname . "</td></tr>";
                                            }
                    ?>

                </table>

                <table id="author">
                    <?php

                                    foreach($user["itemauthors"] as $itemauthor) {

                                            echo "<tr><td class='user'>" . $itemauthor . "</td></tr>";

                                            }
                            ?>

                </table>

                <table id="date">
                    <?php



                                    foreach($user["loandates"] as $loandate) {

                                            $time = strtotime($loandate);
                                            $myFormatForView = date("l d F Y", $time);

                                            echo "<tr><td class='user'>" . $myFormatForView  . "</td></tr>";

                                            }
                            ?>

                </table>

                <table id="duedate">
                    <?php

                                    foreach($user["loanduedates"] as $loanduedate) {

                                            $time = strtotime($loanduedate);
                                            $myFormatForView = date("l d F Y", $time);

                                            echo "<tr><td class='user'>" . $myFormatForView . "</td></tr>";

                                            }
                            ?>

                </table>
```

I ultimately want just one table with one foreach loop rather than four tables with four foreach loops. If you get my meaning.

I would be very thankful if anyone could help! Thanks heaps in advance!!

Regards,

Robert, London UK

Comment: P.S. the results of the database select (in the model code) were all stored into a variable called $user.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $matches[] = array("loandates" => $row["loan_date"],
               "loanduedates" => $row["loan_duedate"],
                "itemnames" => $row["item_name"],
                "itemauthors" => $row["item_author"]);
```

Now you have one array and you can display it with one foreach.

```
foreach($matches as $match) {
   echo $match['loandates'] . '</td><td>' . $match['loan_duedate'] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // we loop through the loans one at a time, and add them to our matches variable
     $matches[] = $row;
 }
```

And then:

```
<table id="name">

<?php 
    foreach($user as $key=>$values) { 
       echo '<tr>';
       foreach($values as $itemname) {
        //echo <td> with data
       }
       echo '</tr>';
    }
```